# File upload cant insert to mysqli database

Tags: php, mysqli

[this is what my database looks like after inserting all the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VQB1.png)
so i created an array from my previous file and in this loop it should check the file for each index and after checking it should be store in a variable $filename. after inputting all the fields from the previous file in successfully inserted to the database but it failed to upload the file in photo column please help i don't know wheres the error since it would not echo the error in my if statement and i'm still learning to store array of files please help.

```
for ($i=0; $i < $loop; $i++) { 
    $filename = NULL; 
    $sellingPrice = $_POST['unit_price'][$i]/$_POST['quantity'][$i];
    if (isset($_FILES['prodPhoto'][$i]) && count($_FILES['prodPhoto'][$i]) > 4) {
        if ($_FILES['prodPhoto']['type'][$i] == "image/png" || $_FILES['prodPhoto']['type'][$i] == "image/jpeg") {
            if ($_FILES['prodPhoto']['size'][$i] <= 10000000) {
                $filename = "../prod_images".$_FILES['prodPhoto']['name'][$i];
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['prodPhoto']['tmp_name'][$i], $filename);
            }
        }
    }
    $insertProduct = "INSERT INTO `products` (prod_name, `type`, `desc`, 
                      `unit_price`, `qty`, `status`, `photo`, `trans_id`, `supplier_id`) VALUES ('{$_POST['prod_name'[$i]}', 
                            '{$_POST['productType'][$i]}', 
                            '{$_POST['desc'][$i]}',  
                            ".$sellingPrice.", 
                            '{$_POST['quantity'][$i]}',
                            'available', 
                            '{$filename}', 
                            ".$transac_id.", 
                            '{$_POST['addSupplier'][$i]}' )";

    $productResult = mysqli_query($conn,$insertProduct);
    if ($productResult) {
        echo "SUCCESSFULLY INSERTED";
    }else{
        echo mysqli_error($conn);
    }                       
}
```

Comment: could you debug your code and say where it fails ? does teh file get uploaded? does an sql error apear ?

Comment: actually it didn't fail  but when ever i check my database  all the data that was inputted are being inserted to the database except for the file

Comment: you got an error there : VALUES ('{$_POST['prod_name'[$i]} this should be VALUES ('{$_POST['prod_name'][$i]}

Comment: yeah i already fix that but it did not fix my problem with the file upload

Comment: the file wont get inserted, do you mean teh filename or what is your goal ? is the file in the directory you uploaded into ?

Comment: the file it means the image that i was trying to insert also into the database

Comment: Pleas show a current database entry, what happend when you upload some files (edit your post)

Comment: i already uploaded a photo of my database after uploading all data @BlackNetworkBit

Comment: So no file got uploaded .... pleas check if the $_FILES contains any data.

Comment: yes it contains data i already use <pre> tag and it shows the information of the $_FILES

Comment: If value of photo column is null, that mean one of your tests failed. Did you try to debug step by step? Test of image type (image/png or image/jpeg) seems strict, are you sure of uploaded images types?

Comment: And your index $i is use in a strange matter, once `isset($_FILES['prodPhoto'][$i])`, once `$_FILES['prodPhoto']['type'][$i]`,... try to do a var_dump of $_FILES['prodPhoto'] to see what you have in it